# How to set precision for EL division on JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el

How can I set  precision for such EL result?

```
<h:outputText value="#{businessPlanPreviewBean.plan.a1 != 0 ?
 businessPlanPreviewBean.plan.a2/businessPlanPreviewBean.plan.a3 : 0 } " >
</h:outputText>
```

I tried 
`<f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" />`
but no luck...

`<f:convertNumber pattern="#,##" />` - the same thing

Mojarra JSF implementation version 1.2_14-b01-FCS

Comment: Have you tried the `pattern` attribute ?

Comment: You really need to elaboarate the requirements and the problem in more detail. Give some examples of input and **both** the expected and *actual* output. Maybe you're expecting a completely different outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was very simple. "value" attribute contains unnecessary space at the end. So, value has string type in this case.

String cannot be formatted with `f:convertNumber.`